# position and override the default nftables rules

Tags: networking, centos, firewall, boot, nftables

I recently installed Centos8 on a virtual machine to try nftables as a replacement for iptables.
I installed it by choosing the full server with GUI option.
With `nft list rulset` I have a long output with various rules that I don't need, I want to use the file `/etc/nftables/main.nft` which I have slightly modified for my needs. With `nft -f /etc/nftables/main.nft` I can load them and everything works fine but I can't figure out how to make them persistent (I thought it read by default the file in etc but apparently it doesn't it is so) n where the default rules are saved.
How do I make it use the rules in main.nft by default and at boot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RESOLVED:
In centos8 you need to edit /etc/sysconfig/nftables.conf and uncomment the line include "/etc/nftables/main.nft" to use the sample file.
thank you very much, myself